# Using Eclipse Helios for Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I need to build a web project using Eclipse Helois (3.6).
I found a tutorial on the web on a SchoolProject.

Please post information about some other tutorials available on the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some good examples:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-helios/index.html
http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html
http://www.michael-thomas.com/tech/apache/tomcat/tutorial_tomcat_eclipse/index.htm

Hope these helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [Eclipse's official help site](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/ccwebprj.html) should help you get started.